# Laravel Eloquent: Get percentage completed from tasks

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a tasks table that includes project id and progress completed(0-100)

| id | project_id | progress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 3 | 45 |
| 3 | 1 | 35 |
| 4 | 3 | 100 |

The result I am looking for is:
project 1 = 27.5%
project 3 = 72.5%

My code to get the task is as follows
`$project->tasks()`

Comment: So what have you tried? Seems like you want to average the percentages... try running a Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following. Convention says the relationship would be called `tasks`:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

public function progress()
{
    return $this->tasks()->average('progress');
}
```

Then you can get the progress of the tasks for each project:

```
Project::find(1)->progress();

// or

$project = Project::find(1);
$project->progress();
```

Comment: @johntully Try to make accessor for this.

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
     DB::table('table_name')->selectRaw('id, project_id, sum(progress) / 
     count(progress) as percentage')->groupBy('project_id')
     ->get();
```